# Why I cannot delete a class instance in python

Tags: python, oop

I want to delete a class instance or make it None in python. But I'm not able to do it. In general my code does something as follows:-

```
class Foo:
  pass

f = Foo()
g = Foo()
f.attr = g
h = f.attr
del h
print f.attr  # This is not None but it should be right?
```

More specifically this problem came while implementing binary search trees in python. My delete function does something like this:-

```
class Tree:
  def delete(self, key):
    min_right = self.right.getmin()
    self.key = min_right.key
    del min_right  # Does not work
```

Am I doing something wrong or is it expected behavior? If it is expected, what is the best way by OOP standards to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: What you have been doing is to delete `h` not `f.attr`.

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to achieve?

Comment: For us to help you in the case of your binary search tree, we would need more code.

Answer (score 3):

You have a situation that looks like this:

```
                  g

                  |

     <__main__.Foo object at 0x...>

          /               \

       f.attr               h
```

i.e. three *references* to the **same underlying object**. All that `del h` does is *remove the name `h`*, like this:

```
                  g

                  |

     <__main__.Foo object at 0x...>

          /               

       f.attr
```

The underlying object doesn't change, and the two other names still provide a reference to it, all you've done is remove one reference to the `Foo` instance. `h` is now a `NameError`, but `g` and `f.attr` will work just fine.

> ```
>  # This is not None but it should be right?
> ```

I don't know why you would conclude that - if you *did* succeed in breaking the reference from `f.attr` to the `Foo` instance, you would get an `AttributeError`, not `None`.

Recommended reading on Python names: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 1):

That is because deleting an object does not automatically delete objects that it references.

Meaning lets say we have -

```
l = [1,2,3]

l1 = l
```

When we do `del l` , it deletes the name `l` , not the object it references. Example -

```
In [34]: l = [1,2,3]

In [35]: l1 = l

In [36]: del l

In [37]: l1
Out[37]: [1, 2, 3]
```

It just decreases the reference for the object by 1, when the references for an object reaches `0` it can get garbage collected.

So in your binary search tree case, when you do -

```
del min_right
```

You are just deleting the local variable/name `min_right` , not the object it references.

Answer (score 1):

To delete the attribute:

```
del f.attr
```

It will be gone and not `None`.

To set it to `None`:

```
f.attr = None
```

Don't use an intermediate variable!

Answer (score 1):

## some change

```
class Foo(object):
  pass

f = g = Foo()
f.attr = g
h = f.attr
del h
print(f.attr)
```

output, t3 is python file t3.py

```
>>> t3.f
<t3.Foo object at 0x7ff1074b7e48>

>>> t3.g
<t3.Foo object at 0x7ff1074b7e48>

>>> t3.f.attr
<t3.Foo object at 0x7ff1074b7e48>
```

Although you delete the `h`, the object was still referenced by `g` and `f`.

### gc

Python use reference count to reclaim memory.

Comment: This answer is correct, but a little unclear. Try to elaborate on your explanation as the OP probably doesn't understand the source of the problem.